# SQLITE: database is locked error (error - 5) when used update query

Tags: sqlite

```
int nRet = sqlite3_open(szFile, &mpDB);

if (nRet != SQLITE_OK)
{

}

setBusyTimeout(mnBusyTimeoutMs);

   sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "Begin Transaction;", 0, 0, &szError);
  sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "UPDATE query", 0, 0, &szError);//some update table query
sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "Commit Transaction;", 0, 0, &szError);///Here it gives error database is locked
```

Above code works fine for insert command instead of update command.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads involved?

Comment: I hope "UPDATE query" is not your real sql-statement

Answer (score 3):

Do you have that file opened in some sql editor, in the same time? I've recently used program called "SQLite database browser" and it locked my whole sqlite database, it took me some time to find out what the hell is going on.

Comment: @sandip123: Do you have any "-journal" files next to the file? Maybe something went wrong earlier and it locked the database, try deleting these files.

Comment: No .journal files in database folder. I am wondering how it's working for insert command and not for update

Comment: @sandip123: Try executing this query on another new fresh .sqlite file. Btw. Is this transaction required? Isn't there something like autocommit mode?

Comment: @ Czarek: without transaction it gives error to sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "UPDATE query", 0, 0, &szError);

Comment: @sandip123: Can you provide the full code? Add more error handling, you're not checking the sqlite3_open() result.

Comment: wrapper with following function
 void temp::open(const char* szFile)
{
 sqlite3_open(szFile, &mpDB);
 setBusyTimeout(1500);
}

temp::BeginTransaction()
{
 m_DB.execDML("begin transaction;");
}
temp::CommitTransaction()
{
  m_DB.execDML("commit;");
 
}
int temp::execDML(const char* szSQL)
{
 char* szError=0;
 int nRet = sqlite3_exec(mpDB, szSQL, 0, 0, &szError);
 return nRet;
}

Calling wrapper

wrapper.open(fname);
BeginTransaction()
Cstring str = UPDATE MYTable SET PARTS_MOVED = 1, CONT_MOVED = 1.00, TSQ_MOVED = 1.00, MOVE_FREQ = 1.00
wrapper.execDML(str)
CommitTransaction()

Comment: @sandip123: what error message you get when not using transaction? it shouldn't be required.

Comment: @sandip123: then try executing this query on another .sqlite database file, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @ Czarek: getting simillar error on another file as well. Actually I am coverting one application from MS Access to Sqlite. previously in Access there is lot of table and data so I used import from Sqlite2009pro to convert access to sqlite. And using this Sqlite (.db3) file in my application

Comment: @sandip123: then see the sources of these exports... maybe the bug is there. Also try creating an empty sqlite database with only 1 simple table and make insert/update to it, to check whether the error is not in your code.

Comment: I  am having application where I shows data from database in fact we can say it's database editor.From C# (.net api) I am able to update data from database.But from C++ I am getting error 5 (database is locked).