# SQLite database update in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have an application where I show data from a database. In fact we can say it's a database editor.

Now I want to perform update/delete command on this opened database. Using the following commands, the database opens successfully.

```
int nRet = sqlite3_open(szFile, &mpDB);
```

From C# (.net api) I am able to update data from database

```
dbCmd5 = New SQLiteCommand(
        "update Tbl_Tmp_Cal_Res Load_Time=5  WHERE Part_Index= 5", g_dbFlow);
dbCmd5.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But from C++ I am getting error 5 (database is locked)

C++ code

```
int nRet = sqlite3_open(szFile, &mpDB);//database opened successfully.
sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "UPDATE query", 0, 0, &szError);//Error for this statement
```

Multithreading is not used in application.

Comment: Is there another program that uses the database at the same time?

Comment: No other program using it. it's working fine with C#

Comment: what is the error (szError variable) ?

Comment: also, have you tried the c++ sample? http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: Duplicate of the same question you asked 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137106/sqlite-database-is-locked-error-error-5-when-used-update-query/8137175#8137175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the database used from another location in the code?  Since something else clearly seems to have the database locked, I would guess that you're using the database from another location in the code and have forgotten to call sqlite3_finalize on a select statement or something similar.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you have forgotten authentication step (username/password & etc)

Comment: -1 because SQLite is not a traditional RDBMS, it has no concept of user, password, ROLE, GRANT or REVOKE.